# How do I convert ruby hash to proper xml format

Tags: ruby, xml, json, hash

Here is the specific XML I ultimately need:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <name>Test name</name>
     <values>
       <elements>123</elements>
       <elements>456</elements>
       <elements>789</elements>
     </values>
```

And I am having a hash looks like:

```
  {
    name: 'Test name' ,
    values: [123, 456, 789],
  }
```

here I want to make duplicate sub elements in an xml.

So, how can I convert the hash to that XML format?

Comment: What is the root element you want?  You example is not a valid XML document but instead an XML declaration and two sequential elements (`name` and `values`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Nokogiri::XML::Builder`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder).

Note that your example is not a valid XML document because it is missing a root element.  Assuming you want a document rooted with an element named `object`:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

h = {
  name: 'Test name' ,
  values: [123, 456, 789],
}

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.object {
    xml.name h[:name]
    xml.values {
      h[:values].each { |v| xml.elements v }
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <object>
#   <name>Test name</name>
#   <values>
#     <elements>123</elements>
#     <elements>456</elements>
#     <elements>789</elements>
#   </values>
# </object>
```